# How to use other LLM in spring ai, such as chatglm

Tags: large-language-model

How to use other Chat Models  in spring ai, such as chatglm . There are no relevant usage instructions in the project documentation。Using code examples。Please provide a code example using another Chat Models Or corresponding documents